# Loop through dates

Tags: sql, date, loops

We have a table to keep track of items in a warehouse:

```
-------------------------
ID     DATEIN     DATEOUT
-------------------------
```

What we need is a list of the amount of items in the warehouse per week.

This is how far we've gotten:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (ID)
FROM
    table
WHERE
    table.DATEIN<=#somedate1#
    AND
    (
        table.DATEOUT>#somedate1#
        OR
        table.DATEOUT IS NULL
    )
```

This gives us the amount of items in the warehouse on date #somedate1#. However, we need a list of the amount per week. (keeping in mind that it's possible that some items stay in the warehouse for months)

The tricky part isn't the week, we can use DATEPART ("ww", #somedate1#), but looping through the dates.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
        SELECT
            DATEPART("ww","D"),COUNT (ID)
        FROM
            (
             SELECT Table.DATEIN as D
             FROM table 
             WHERE table.DATEIN<=#somedate1# AND ( table.DATEOUT>#somedate1# OR   table.DATEOUT IS NULL)
             UNION ALL
             SELECT Table.DATEOUT as D 
             FROM table 
             WHERE table.DATEIN<=#somedate1# AND ( table.DATEOUT>#somedate1# OR table.DATEOUT IS NULL)
            )
        GROUP BY DATEPART("ww","D")
```

First you need to make an `UNION` to make sure you have all `DATEIN` and `DATEOUT`, then you can `GROUP BY`

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what we need. It'll add the week number of the date we specified, but it'll still provide the amount of items only for the week we specify.

Comment: Forget the week number for a moment, that part isn't crucial. If we could get the same result per day instead of per week we'd also have what we need. The problem lies in the fact that we can't loop through the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we've come up with so far.

This code gives a list of all dates where an item came into the warehouse or left. These are the dates we need to apply the code in my first post to. I.e. we need to loop through these dates where for each iteration the next date is used as #somedate1#

```
SELECT
    table.DATEIN AS DATE
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    table.DATEIN
UNION
SELECT
    table.DATEOUT AS DATE
FROM
    table
WHERE
    table.DATEOUT NOT IN (
        SELECT
            table.DATEIN
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY
            table.DATEIN
    )
GROUP BY
    table.DATEOUT
```

We're stuck at how we can loop through them though. Everything we try gives weird results that we're not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

We got it! The answer was staring us right in the face the whole time. This does the trick:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (table1.ID),
    table2.DATE
FROM
    table1,
    (
        SELECT
            table1.DATEIN AS DATE
        FROM
            table1
        GROUP BY
            table1.DATEIN
        UNION
        SELECT
            table1.DATEOUT AS DATE
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            table1.DATEOUT NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    table1.DATEIN
                FROM
                    table1
                GROUP BY
                    table1.DATEIN
            )
        GROUP BY
            table1.DATEOUT
    ) table2
WHERE
    table1.DATEIN<=table2.DATE
    AND
    (
        table1.DATEOUT>table2.DATE
        OR
        table1.DATEOUT IS NULL
    )
GROUP BY
    table2.DATE
```